# XQuery with three separate XML files

Tags: xml, xquery

While attempting to learn XQuery, I am trying to write a query that selects information from <s>three</s> two separate XML files. I have a little bit of experience with XQuery but I just can't think of a good way of structuring this kind of query. Here's the information in the each XML file.

**Person.xml**

```
<AllPersons>
  <Person>
    <Name>Jinchao Henson</Name>
    <ID>118784412</ID>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Min Tuyet</Name>
    <ID>201586985</ID>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>John Basaraba</Name>
    <ID>124208644</ID>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Richard Ellison</Name>
    <ID>997111094</ID>
  </Person>
  ...
</AllPersons>
```

**Student.xml**

```
<AllStudents>
  <Student>
    <StudentID>118784412</StudentID>
    <MentorID>201586985</MentorID>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <StudentID>124208644</StudentID>
    <MentorID>997111094</MentorID>
  </Student>
  ...
</AllStudents>
```

<s>**Faculty.xml**</s>

```
<AllFaculty>
  <Faculty>
    <FacultyID>201586985</FacultyID>
    <Rank>Professor</Rank>
  </Faculty>
  <Faculty>
    <FacultyID>997111094</FacultyID>
    <Rank>Reader</Rank>
  </Faculty>
  ...
</AllFaculty>
```

A homework problem is asking to select each Student and their Mentor. I've attempted to write a query that loops through the Students, selecting the Student node, then two let expressions for the Person and Faculty nodes, then returning a Student's name and a Faculty's name but can't get it to work. I've also tried a query that loops through the Students, a let expression for Faculty, a where clause that matches StudentID to FacultyID and StudentID to Person/ID, then return that Person/Name and then loop through the faculty matching the ID and returning the Name.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:** Thanks for the advice. I Cleaned up XML examples and here is an attempt:

```
for $student in doc("../Student.xml")//Student
let $faculty := doc("../Faculty.xml")//Faculty
let $person := doc("../Person.xml")//Person
where $student/MentorID = $faculty/FacultyID and $student/StudentID = $person/ID
return
  <StudentMentor>{
      $person/Name,
      <Mentor>{
        for $personTwo in doc("../Person.xml")//Person
          where $personTwo/ID = $faculty/FacultyID
          return $personTwo/Name
      }</Mentor>
    }
 </StudentMentor> 
}
```

I'm pretty new to XQuery so I don't know the best way of structuring this query.

**Edit 2:** After looking at the data closer, I guess I don't even need the Faculty.xml file, I'll try to work on a better (actually working) solution.

**Edit 3:** Here is my working solution, please advise how I could make it more efficient.

```
for $student in doc("../Student.xml")//Student
let $personS := doc("../Person.xml")//Person[ID = $student/StudentID]
for $personM in doc("../Person.xml")//Person[ID = $student/MentorID]
return 
  <StudentMentor>
    <Student>{$personS/Name}</Student>,
    <Mentor>{$personM/Name}</Mentor>
  </StudentMentor>
```

Comment: Why not show the query you tried (but can't get to work)? A description of *how* it "doesn't work" would be helpful, too (no results at all? Not pulling in data? Etc).

Comment: Also, the sample data here is poorly chosen, since the IDs in your Person examples don't line up with the IDs in the Student or Faculty examples, preventing anyone from actually demonstrating a working query with that data.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest removing extra data that's not needed to join things together (as it makes your question longer while adding no value) beyond a minimum necessary to identify that content was seen, and *adding* additional entries sufficient that what's given in your question will actually parse -- making it **minimal**, **complete**, and **verifiable**; see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thanks for the advice, it's a little hard to provide decent XML data because of how strange the XML files are structured. The attempt I provided was sort of in between changing it trying to get something that would work.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I've been working on this one problem for a couple hours, I finally achieved a solution but, like you said, I feel like I am still over selecting. I'll post an edit with my solution that correctly returns each student and their mentor. If you could give some advice on how I could improve the query, I'd appreciate it. Thanks again

Comment: As an aside, you have `AllPerson` in one place and `AllPersons` in another. I'm assuming, for the sake of convenience, that the latter is correct.

Comment: Any advice on the efficiency of this query is going to depend strongly on what XQuery processor you are using (and if you're using an XML database, what indexes it has configured). Also of course it will depend on data sizes. As written it looks as if it has quadratic performance, but a good optimizer will avoid that. For example: Saxon-HE and Saxon-EE will give radically different results on join queries like this (Saxon-EE will build an index for fast access to Person elements by ID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better code might look a bit like this:

```
declare variable $students := doc("../Students.xml")/AllStudents/Student;
declare variable $faculty := doc("../Faculty.xml")/AllFaculty/Faculty;
declare variable $persons := doc("../Person.xml")/AllPersons/Person;

for $student in $students
let $faculty := $faculty[FacultyID=$student/MentorID]
let $student_person := $persons[ID=$student/StudentID]
let $faculty_person := $persons[ID=$student/MentorID]
return
  <StudentMentor>{
      $student_person/Name,
      <Mentor>{$faculty_person/Name}</Mentor>
    }</StudentMentor>
```

Using the above with your test data, I get the following output:

```xml
<StudentMentor>
  <Name>Jinchao Henson</Name>
  <Mentor>
    <Name>Min Tuyet</Name>
  </Mentor>
</StudentMentor>
<StudentMentor>
  <Name>John Basaraba</Name>
  <Mentor>
    <Name>Richard Ellison</Name>
  </Mentor>
</StudentMentor>
```

Note:

- There aren't any `where` clauses here; your query doesn't need them, and selecting a huge set of possible permutations and using a where to winnow down is wildly inefficient (or at least, unidiomatic) as opposed to going straight for the data you actually want.
- There's no point to selecting *all* students, or faculty, or persons inside a "let"; anything which will be global to the entire query, as opposed to scoped to the items iterated over with the "for", should be declared as a variable.
- Replacing the use of `//` for a recursive search to instead go through the root node explicitly is more efficient if your database isn't indexed to be able to avoid that recursion. You could use `$students_doc/*/Student` (and likewise for the others) to similar effect.

Comment: Perfect, but you could even eliminate $faculty because it isn't used in your query and doesn't need to be, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks again, super helpful!

Comment: You can remove the `./` from the inside of each predicate as it is redundant. Also you can move the path selections out of the FLOWR which will make the process more efficient as you will have fewer navigations per iteration of the loop, e.g. `declare variable $persons := doc("../Person.xml")/AllPersons/Person;`, `let $student_person := $persons[ID=$student/StudentID]` and `let $faculty_person := $persons[ID=$student/MentorID]`. You can apply that pattern to all the doc() calls in this example